# Lollipop Writing and reading to an from the sd card

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard

I'm making an application for a friend of mine's Sony Xperia D5803 phone. In the application I create data and write it to the SD card. When a user opens the app again, the phone reads it in and does so correctly. I have both permissions for writing and reading to the sd card.

The problem is that while my app reads the stored data from the SD card correctly, I personally can't see the folders and files my app created on the SD card when I open it via Micro USB on Ubuntu. I've tried checking the show hidden files options, but my app's files still do not show in the file manager.

What is also strange is that when I open the app's info in the settings OS says that there is no app data on the SD card, but there is some in the phone itself, which is strange, because I'm using this code to write and read from the SD card:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File cookiesDirectory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/settings/");
cookiesDirectory.mkdirs();
File outputSettings = new File(cookiesDirectory, "settings.txt");
FileOutputStream writersettings = null;
try {
    writersettings = new FileOutputStream(outputSettings);
    writersettings.write(settingsarray.toString().getBytes());
}
finally {
    writersettings.close();
}
```

Comment: "In the application I create data and write it to the sd card" -- your code has nothing to do with "sd card". It is working with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: The same code reads and writes from and to the sd card on my HTC Desire X. I will, however, try your solution! Is it possible that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() points to the sd card in 4.1.1, but in Lollipop, it points to the internal storage and a method like getRemovableStorage() must be called?

Comment: "Is it possible that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() points to the sd card in 4.1.1" -- there are very few devices in the world for which external storage is removable, running Android 4.x-6.0. I do not have an HTC Desire X and cannot confirm whether it is one of those devices (though, given its [limited amount of on-board flash](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_x-4951.php), it is perhaps a bit more likely than average).

Comment: Oh, that must be it. Can you please point me to the right direction as in which function should I be calling to get to the sd card? I've looked up Environment class, and it does not have a getRemovableStorageDirectory() method.

Comment: "which function should I be calling to get to the sd card" -- [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) is not part of the Android SDK prior to Android 4.4.

Comment: I'll investigate a bit further. Thank you for all your replies!